# How do I remove the Palmer penguins CRAN error?

Tags: r, cran

I am using the package for the palmer penguins in R but I keep getting the message:

Error in contrib.url (repos, source): trying to use CRAN without setting a mirror calls......

What am I doing wrong? I would like to knit my R-Markdown but everytime this error comes up. [see also this printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twksK.png)

Comment: Please paste the error directly into your question rather than a screenshot. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `install.packages('palmerpenguins', repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")` ?

Comment: You should only need to install the package once, not every time you knit the document. I'd remove that line entirely.

Comment: I removed the line Gregor and I can knit the markdown. Thanks!